# Помогите с регуляркой: очистить заголовок от лишних bbcode-тэгов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер

Здравствуйте нужна Ваша помощь в построении регулярки.
Есть постоянный текст `[size=24]заголовок[/size]`

Использую регулярку

```
$pattern = '/\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size\]/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $tText['post_text'], $tPaImg, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$titles_p = $tPaImg[0][2];
```

Так парсит только заголовок, так как мне и надо, но некоторые пользователи начали еще править заголовок под свой стиль добавляя теги `b`, `i`, `color` и `font`.
Как правильно составить регулярку, чтобы убирались все теги ббкода и выдирался только текст заголовка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
\]([^\[\]]+)\[
```

https://regex101.com/r/oR6tA5/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oR6tA5/2 - что-то не то.

Comment: То что надо. Работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Visman, в регулярках да, но тут же используется preg_match_all и на выходе массив из всех совпадений получаем

Comment: Заметил минус существенный, страница на 4 секунды дольше грузиться стала при выводе 20 результатов на одну страницу

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, воспользоваться дополнительным регулярным выражением

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/size\]/i';
$text = '[size=2345][i][b]title[/b][/i][/size]';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $tPaImg, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo preg_replace('/\[[^\]]+\]/', '', $tPaImg[0][2]);
```